# Computed property not updating in production build

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I have a computed property named `wildcardItem` that is working when using a development build, but when I run the production build (`mix --production`), the property is no longer updating.

I'm using Laravel Mix to compile the code.

```js
mix.setPublicPath('../')
    .js('js/app.js', 'dist/app.js')
    .vue()
    .postCss('css/app.css', 'dist/app.css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('@tailwindcss/nesting'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
    ])
    .options({
        manifest: false,
    });
```

#### Component Setup

```
const items = ref([]);
const query = ref('');

const wildcardItem = computed(_ => {
    console.log('Computing wildcard...');

    return {
        label: query.value,
    };
});

document.addEventListener('CustomEvent', function (event) {
    items.value = [
        ...event.detail.items,
        wildcardItem,
    ];
});
```

#### Component Template

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <input v-model="query" />
        <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="`item-${index}`">
            {{ item.label }}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I also don't see my `console.log` when running with the production build.

Can someone please guide me on why it's not working? :)

Comment: Though I probably shouldn't ask, are you actually returning items,query, and wildcardItem from setup?

Comment: @Issayah I don't need to return using Vue3 setup https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#reactivity

Comment: I've never used that style before. I've only used <script>setup(){}</script> syntax. Neat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`computed()` returns a `ref`, so you need to use `.value` to unwrap the `ref` for the value:

```js
document.addEventListener('CustomEvent', function (event) {
    items.value = [
        ...event.detail.items,
        //wildcardItem, ❌
        wildcardItem.value, ✅
    ];
});
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-computed-props?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyItems.vue)

Alternatively, you could use the [reactivity transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html), which does not require any unwrapping (no `.value` needed). Instead of importing `ref` and `computed`, use `$ref` and `$computed` (no imports needed):

```html
<script setup>
let items = $ref([])
let query = $ref('')

const wildcardItem = $computed(_ => {
  console.log('Computing wildcard...')

  return {
    label: query,
  }
})

document.addEventListener('CustomEvent', function (event) {
  items = [
    ...event.detail.items,
    wildcardItem,
  ]
})
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-computed-props-tghbbt?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyItems.vue)

Another issue you were seeing was that `items` was not updated when `wildcardItem` changed. You would need to refactor your solution to make `items` a `computed` property based on the `wildcardItem` appended to items from the custom event:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const customEventItems = ref([])
const query = ref('')

const wildcardItem = computed(_ => {})

const items = computed(() => [...customEventItems.value, wildcardItem.value])

document.addEventListener('CustomEvent', function (event) {
  customEventItems.value = [...event.detail.items]
})
</script>
```

[demo 3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-using-computed-props-nnp8l2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyItems.vue)